# How to combine tables produced by stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and it outputs value as table pf two columns. This is in SQL Server

```
exec infos @tablee = 'tem', @dbs = 'tempdb', @columns = 'revenue'

exec infos @tablee = 'tem', @dbs = 'tempdb', @columns = 'price'
```

When I execute this with separate values then it create separate tables for each execution. Is there any way to combine all tables into one .

```
max             5000
mean            5000
median          5000
min             5000
nulls              0
nun null count    24
std. dev           0
total         120000
total count       24
```

Another table

```
max              40
mean             40
median           40
min              40
nulls             0
nun null count   24
std. dev          0
total           960
total count      24
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE2`

Comment: but its not table, the output is as a table. so i cant give the procedure in from clause

Comment: Create a temporary table. Then `INSERT INTO .... EXEC` twice followed by `SELECT FROM` your temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording makes it sound as if the stored procedure is creating an actual table rather than simply outputting a dataset. I believe what you are asking is how to insert the output of a stored procedure into table and then display the output.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpinfos
(
   stat_test VARCHAR(20),
   test_value INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpinfos
exec infos @tablee = 'tem', @dbs = 'tempdb', @columns = 'revenue'

INSERT INTO #tmpinfos
exec infos @tablee = 'tem', @dbs = 'tempdb', @columns = 'price'

SELECT * from #tmpinfos
```

While the above works you need to also include the @columns in the output of the stored procedure so that you can separate 'revenue' and 'price' for obvious reasons. Or you can update after each insert:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpinfos
(
   test_category VARCHAR(20),
   stat_test VARCHAR(20),
   test_value INT
)

INSERT INTO #tmpinfos(stat_test, test_value)
exec infos @tablee = 'tem', @dbs = 'tempdb', @columns = 'revenue'
UPDATE #tmpinfos SET test_category = 'revenue' WHERE test_category IS NULL;

INSERT INTO #tmpinfos
exec infos @tablee = 'tem', @dbs = 'tempdb', @columns = 'price'
UPDATE #tmpinfos SET test_category = 'price' WHERE test_category IS NULL;

SELECT * from #tmpinfos
```